# Why does my FlywayMigrationStrategy call afterMigrate.sql twice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I work on a Spring-boot project and use Flyway for database migration.
While working in dev-profile I want to fill the database with dummy data.
In order to have the exact same initial data values I overrode the FlywayMigrationStrategy Bean so that it performs a flyway.clean() before the migration starts:

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() {
    FlywayMigrationStrategy strategy = new FlywayMigrationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
        }
    };

    return strategy;
}
```

My Migration folder contains several versioned migration scripts and ONE afterMigrate callback script which adds data to the created Tables.

[image]

The problem now is, the afterMigrate.sql script gets called two times as you can see from the following log:

```
2017-07-03 13:12:42.332  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Successfully cleaned schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.031s)
2017-07-03 13:12:42.397  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 4 migrations (execution time 00:00.044s)
2017-07-03 13:12:42.413  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl  : Creating Metadata table: "PUBLIC"."schema_version"
2017-07-03 13:12:42.428  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2017-07-03 13:12:42.430  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - create users
2017-07-03 13:12:42.449  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - create address
2017-07-03 13:12:42.464  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 3 - create patient case
2017-07-03 13:12:42.475  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 4 - state machine
2017-07-03 13:12:42.498  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 4 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.086s).
2017-07-03 13:12:42.499  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.c.SqlScriptFlywayCallback        : Executing SQL callback: afterMigrate
2017-07-03 13:12:42.502  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.c.SqlScriptFlywayCallback        : Executing SQL callback: afterMigrate
2017-07-03 13:12:42.917  INFO 23222 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
```

If I remove the flyway.clean() function call it gets called only once.

Can somebody tell me why its called twice when I call flyway.clean() and flyway.migrate() and how to prevent the second call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue which will be fixed in Flyway 5.0. See https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1653

Comment: Thanks for the information. I hope the bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: This is now fixed with version 5.0.1. Thanks to Alex and all contributers.

Comment: Hm, I don't think the problem comes from FlywayDB but [in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301584/configuration-for-flywaymigrationstrategy-not-working-after-deployment) this part gets not executed after deployment.